Hello How to Force expo app to be just RTL?
I have an app is written in expo and all things in the app use "Arabic Language"
So I want to force the app to be RTL, so I use supportsRTL and forcesRTL to do it and it's work fine in debugging version "when my mobile language LTR OR RTL it's work perfectly"
here is my app.json
{
  "expo": {
 "extra": {
      "supportsRTL": true,
      "forcesRTL": true
    },
  }
}

but when I release a apk version for play store when my mobile language RTL "Arabic" the layout and other things works fine, BUT when my mobile language be LTR "English" the layout changes in the first load but if iclosed the app and reopen it it works correctly
SO i want to force my app to be RTL whether the mobile language "Arabic or English"
this is my localization provider
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import * as Localization from "expo-localization";
import { I18n } from "i18n-js";
import { translations } from "../localization";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const LocalizationContext = createContext();

export const LocalizationProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState(Localization.getLocales()[0].languageTag);
  const i18n = new I18n(translations);
  i18n.locale = locale;
  i18n.enableFallback = true;
  i18n.defaultLocale = "ar";

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocale = async () => {
      const storedLocale = await AsyncStorage.getItem('selectedLocale');
      if (storedLocale) {
        setLocale(storedLocale);
      }
    };
    fetchLocale();
  }, []);

  const handleLocaleChange = async (newLocale) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('selectedLocale', newLocale);
    setLocale(newLocale);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationContext.Provider value={{ locale, setLocale: handleLocaleChange, t: i18n.t.bind(i18n) }}>
      {children}
    </LocalizationContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useLocalization = () => {
  return useContext(LocalizationContext);
};

i surrounded my app with it
export default function App() {
return (
    <LocalizationProvider>
       <NavigationContainer>
       </NavigationContainer>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

